# Creating Dynamic Query in Stored Procedure MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-error-1064

**I have a Table and Rows in table like below**

```
CREATE TABLE Areas(AreaName VARCHAR(255),
                    PinCode VARCHAR(255))

INSERT INTO Areas(AreaName, PinCode)
      VALUES('Teynampet', '6000018'), 
            ('Ramapuram', '6000089'),
            ('TNagar', '6000017'), 
            ('Mylapore', '6000014'), 
            ('Gopalapuram', '6000087')
```

**I Wrote a SQL Procedure as Below**

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS mp_test;
CREATE PROCEDURE mp_test(IN pArea VARCHAR(255))
   BEGIN
      SET @Query = 'SELECT PinCode FROM Areas';

      IF pArea != ''
      THEN
         SET @City = CONCAT(' WHERE AreaName = ', pArea);
      END IF;

      SET @Query = CONCAT(@Query, @City);

 PREPARE stmt FROM @Query;
 EXECUTE stmt;
END
```

**When I Call the Procedure**

```
CALL mp_test('Teynampet');
```

When i Execute i am Not getting the Desired result i.e is 600018

How can i build query dynamically in SP

Thanks for the Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're concatenating the `pArea` parameter into the SQL unquoted.  That is, the content of `@Query` that you prepare for execution is:

```
SELECT PinCode FROM Areas WHERE AreaName = Teynampet
```

Since `Teynampet` is unquoted, it is parsed as a(n unknown) SQL identifier rather than a string.  You should either:

- quote it in your SQL:

  ```
  SET @City  = CONCAT(' WHERE AreaName = ', QUOTE(pArea));
  ```
- pass it to the prepared statement as a parameter:

  ```
  SET @City  = CONCAT(' WHERE AreaName = ?');
  SET @param = pArea;
  ```

  and then:

  ```
  EXECUTE stmt USING @param;
  ```

However, why use prepared statements here?  Your procedure can be rewritten as a simple `SELECT` (which raises the question of whether you need to use a stored procedure at all):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE mp_test(IN pArea VARCHAR(255))
  SELECT PinCode FROM Areas WHERE pArea IN (AreaName, '');
```

(Note that I'd recommend you use `NULL` instead of the empty string `''`, in which case the above test would be `pArea IS NULL OR pArea = AreaName`).

Comment: Thanks for Reply I will Use Null